# How is a temporary value type boxed

Tags: c#

This may be an odd question, but I want to know how this is achieved.

Consider the following snippet (in which I for whatever reason decided to box in an array of reference types, instead of just creating the T array)

```
public class HeapScatteredValueList<T> where T : struct
{
    private object[] _list;
    private int _head;

    public HeapScatteredValueList(int maxCapacity)
    {
        _list = new object[maxCapacity];
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        var newHead = _head + 1;
        if (newHead > _list.Length - 1)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        _list[_head++] = item;
    } // The "item" that was copied in to the stack of this function should be destroyed here, what is in the list then?

    public T this[int index] => (T) _list[index];
}
```

Now whenever I call this function, since `T` will be a value type, the argument I am passing in is passed by value (so a copy). This copy should only live in the scope of `Add(T item)` so on the line `_list[_head++] = item` what exactly happens? Where is the `object` in that position of the array pointing to...

Comment: It boxes the value type into an object and stores the object reference in the array. Judging by the text of your question, it seems you already knew this, can you clarify what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Value types and reference types always passing by **value**, until you will use `ref`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen The how, what happens behind the scenes, is it a memcopy over to the heap? Can the runtime know that I am about to do this and allocate the struct on the heap to begin with?

Comment: _what exactly happens?_  - you can approximate it in pseudo code as `_list[_head++] = new object(item);` The item is copied again, this time to the Heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .Net has IL statement to box value type - `box`.
The box operation does following:

1. Allocates the memory considering the size of the value type (plus additional fields - type object pointer and the sync block index)
2. **Copy** the value to this new memory
3. The address of the memory is returned thus becoming reference

The original value type has no relation with this reference. It will be lost when it goes out of scope, but reference remains till it is garbage collected.